# how to latebind click handler after ajax call without using callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

we are trying to create a custom cms where when inside anchor tag you put a rel attribute and a target position and it automatically  attach a click that can fetch data from specified location in rel tag. again new content(came through ajax) can have anchor tag with rel attribute.

how can i achieve it without using callback
current code

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

$("a[rel $= txt]").each(function(index, element) {
       $(this).click(function(){


           var path = $(this).attr("rel");
           path = "./"+path;

           var target = $(this).attr("data-target")


           $(target).load(path, function(){    
                 $("a[rel $= txt]", this).each(function(){
                     $(this).click(function(){
                         var path = $(this).attr("rel");
                          path = "./"+path;
                           $("#result").load(path,function(){
                               $.getScript("js/common.js")
                               });

                         })
                     });
                 $.getScript("js/common.js");

               })
           })//click ended

    });

})
```

Comment: Do you have some sample HTML? And, what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: anchors are like  
<a rel="data-home.txt" data-target="#_home" data-slide="0" id="ln-home">Home</a>
holders are like
<li id="_home" class="vs-li"></li>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$(match-expression).live('click',function(){})` to attach a click handler to all matching elements, even those that are created dynamically later. In your case, `$("a[rel $= txt]").live('click',function(){})` will allow you to attach a click handler to all matching anchors.